# Override FROM image's ENV in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, overriding, dockerfile, env

From the following image: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/cloudesire/activemq/dockerfile/

If I wanted to override the ACTIVEMQ_VERSION environment variable in my child docker file, I assumed I would be able to do something like the following:

```
FROM cloudesire/activemq:latest
MAINTAINER abc <abc@xyz.co.uk>
ENV ACTIVEMQ_VERSION 5.9.1
ADD ./src/main/resources/* /opt/activemq/conf/
```

However this does not seem to work. Admittedly I am new to Docker and have obviously misunderstood something. Please could someone explain why this does not work, and how/if I can achieve it another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That won't work. The `ACTIVEMQ_VERSION` has already been used by the `cloudesire/activemq:latest` image build to populate its image layers. All the ActiveMQ installation files based on version `5.11.1` are already extracted in their corresponding directories.

In your `Dockerfile` you only can build on top of what has already been build there and add your files. Your own `Dockerfile` build will **not re-run** the build instructions described in their `Dockerfile`.

If you need to have your own `cloudesire/activemq` image based on version 5.9.1 you need to clone their `Dockerfile`, adjust the version there and build it locally. So you could base your other `Dockerfile` on it.