# How to add JBOSS_HOME in dockerfile and run the jboss container

Tags: docker, jboss, jboss-wildfly-11

I want to add my custom **`JBOSS_HOME`** but when i run my dockerfile it give me an error.

**`JBOSS_HOME`** may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur.

Unable to access jarfile

```
/home/shri/opt/jboss/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar
```

***MY Dockerfile is:-***

```
FROM jboss/wildfly   
MAINTAINER shri  
USER root  
ENV JBOSS_HOME /home/shri/opt/jboss/wildfly  
RUN mkdir -p  $JBOSS_HOME  
ADD jboss-modules.jar /home/shri/jboss/wildfly/  
USER jboss
```

**build dockerfile using:**

`docker build -t jboss` .

**Run dockerfile using:**

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jboss
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override FROM image's ENV in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834100/override-from-images-env-in-dockerfile)

Comment: Possibly other error, I tried with your dockerfile and then run container with -it (like ssh into the container) given file structure was created and jar file was added.

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile is fine, It is adding your custom jar file as well, Then where is the Problem?

I think the base image you are using setting working directory. to /opt/jboss and there is a default jboss file. I think by default it is picking this jar file.

Try changing working directory, Add this line (or similar) to your docker file after setting ENV and then try

```
WORKDIR ${JBOSS_HOME}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what you are trying to achieve.

The WildFly in the parent image you are building from is located in the `/opt/jboss/wildfly`, but you are

- adding a custom `jboss-modules.jar` to `/home/shri/jboss/wildfly/`
- and setting `JBOSS_HOME` to `/home/shri/opt/jboss/wildfly` which obviously doesn't exist.

If you want just to use the custom `jboss-modules.jar`, then the simplest is to overwrite the original one in `/opt/jboss/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar` and leave the `JBOSS_HOME` unchanged.

You can also have a look at Dockerfile for wildfly on git here: https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/wildfly/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: I do not understand why you are suggesting to over-write jar? Is it not sufficient to set JBOSS_HOME and keep jar there?

Comment: No it's not sufficient. The `jboss-modules.jar` is not enough - it's just something like kernel, you need to provide whole installation in the JBOSS_HOME (i.e. modules, configuration, deployment, ...)